# Trouble with AWS Cognito, API Gateway, Amplify. Requests are always anonymous and return a 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I'm trying to make authenticated requests to API Gateway where I've set a Resource Policy which restricts access to some resources to a IAM role.

No matter the settings I try, all requests to a resource protected by the IAM role return a 403 with the message "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource "

Looking at cloudwatch logs I see that `context.identity` and `context.authorizer.principalId` are always '-'

I'm using aws-amplify/ui-react to configure the front end app and added my user pool, identity pool and API resulting in a config like this:

(truncated a bit)

```
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "us-east-1:bla-blabla-bla-blabla",
    "aws_cognito_region": "us-east-1",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "us-east-1_XXXXXXXXX",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "foostuffboostuff",
    "oauth": {
        "domain": "jefarr-test.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com"
    },
    "aws_cloud_logic_custom": [
         {
             "name": "Cognito Test API",
             "endpoint": "https://foobar.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Test",
             "region": "us-east-1"
         }
     ]
 
};
```

and my React app looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Amplify, Auth, API } from 'aws-amplify';
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

import awsmobile from './aws-exports.js';
Amplify.configure(awsmobile)

function App({ signOut, user }) {

    async function callApi() {
      const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      const token = "Bearer: " + user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken
      const apiName = 'Cognito Test API';
      const path = '/';
  
      const requestData = {
          // headers: { // tried this from the docs, it didn't work.
          //   Authorization: token
          // }
      }
      const data = await API.get(apiName, path, requestData)
      console.log("data: ", data)
    }
        
    return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
      <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
      <button onClick={callApi}>Call Api</button>
    </>
  
  );
}
export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

lastly, here's the relevant Resource Policy on the Gateway:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::840866145964:role/service-role/jefarr-cognito-test-identity-pool-role"
      },
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:840866145964:pu0xzl6eb9/*/*/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've configured a User Pool and an App Client.
I've configured a Identity Pool with a role for authenticated and guest access (matches the above policy), and configured an Identity Provider associated with the app client ID from my user pool.

Looking at the dev tools, I see requests to:

```
AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.GetUser
AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetCredentialsForIdentity
AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetId
```

But when I look at the idToken and accessToken via javascript console I don't see an entry for `cognito:roles` or any indication that the Identity Pool info is included.

Comment: As per the code, it looks you have commented the code for bearer token in `requestData `.

Comment: The idToken contains no roles, and adding it to the request header as a Bearer token results in the same 403 response.

Comment: Did you inspect ID Token at jwt.io?

Comment: You are mixing two things. API Gateway can be secured in 3 ways. Using IAM, Cognito authorisation or Lambda Authorizer. You are passing Cognito token and applied IAM policies on API Gateway, that will never work. Instead you should use Cognito Authorizer at API Gateway.